# When should I use the — sign?

Tags: пунктуация

I'd like to know when I should use the `—` sign in sentences like this:

> Это как собирать базу данных ? не все элементы определены, а уж связи между ними ? тем более.

The symbol **?** marks parts I'm not entirely sure about.

Comment: Также, я хотел бы узнать, можно ли задавать вопросы полностью на русском, не смотря на то что вся группа сайтов StackExchange англоязычная.

Comment: модно задавать вопросы на русском, но если получается на английском -  лучше на английском - так для большего количества людей этот вопрос будет ценным (большее количество людей банально сможет его прочесть).

Comment: @shabunс Мы как раз обсуждали этот вопрос на [мета](http://meta.russian.stackexchange.com/questions/246/answers-are-too-many-questions-are-too-few) всего лишь пару часов назад.  Посмотрите на сообщения от Malcolm и от меня и комментарии под моим последним сообщением.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct syntax is

> Это как собирать базу данных: не все элементы определены, а уж связи между ними — тем более.

Двоеточие (`:`) is used in the first place, because you have a causation clause, you can put *because* there.

In the second place you use Тире (`—`), because there are implied skipped words *не определны*.

Consider:

> Это как собирать базу данных, *[потому что*] не все элементы определены, а уж связи между ними [*не определены*] и подавно.

Answer (score 3):

There are 19 different cases of using m-dash in russian:

http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/42.htm

I am almost sure that no-one, except professionals, really remembers them all :-). Your case is 80.3: missing word,  what was already said in previous comment.

Answer (score 2):

Это как собирать базу данных: не все элементы определены, а уж связи между ними — тем более.